# NSWindow setLevel strange behavior on os x Sierra

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, macos-sierra

I have an application with NSWindow. I'm moving the window programmatically by calling (on the main thread) for:

```
[NSWindow setLevel:level]; //Sometimes I need to change the level
[NSWindow setFrame:frame];
```

The window doesn't move smoothly and with strange black tailing.

But, if I call for once only for

```
[NSWindow setLevel:level];
```

Then the window start to move smoothly.

What may be the reason that when calling both API's I'm getting the strange behavior but if calling once for the `setLevel` API and then continue as before (calling for both API) solves the problem?

Comment: is this a Sierra only problem or would you have the same problem on ElCapitan?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Didn't have this issue on ElCapitan. Only on Sierra.